# Замыкания в javascript

Tags: javascript

Изучаю сейчас функции и замыкания, возник вот такой вопрос

```
function makeCounter() {
  var currentCount = 1;

  return function() {
    return currentCount++;
  };
}
```

здесь возвращается результат второй функции, то есть увеличенный на единицу currentCount.

```
function makeFunc() {
  var name = "Mozilla";
  function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }
  return displayName;
};
```

а что возвращается вот в этом примере? Это ведь не выполнение функции, что значит запись return имя функции без круглых скобок. И в каких случаях нужно использовать первый вариант,а в каких второй?

Comment: Оба варианта одинаковы

Comment: _здесь возвращается результат второй функции_ - не угадал, здесь возвращается **вторая** функция